# Why is it showing Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I call the following thread form `MainActivity` by calling the method `StartQuery().start();`

But i'm having some mysterious problem (for me its mysterious :( ).

`Thread` inside the method like this:

```
private Thread startQuery(){
    return new Thread(() -> {

        for(int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_QUERY && isThreadAlive; i++){

            int tempTime = timePerQuery;
            txtUserResultInput.setText("");
            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.txtCorrectness);
            tv.setText("");


            int finalI = i;
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                Random random = new Random();
                int num1 = Math.abs(random.nextInt(maxNumb1)), num2 = Math.abs(random.nextInt(maxNumb2));
                Log.i("test", num1 + " - " + num2);
                String strNum1 = num1 + "", strNum2 = num2 + "";
                txtOp.setText(typeOfOperation);
                equalizeNumbers(strNum1, strNum2, num1, num2);
                queryCount = finalI;
                String count = "Query No: " + queryCount;
                txtQueryCount.setText(count);
            });

            while (tempTime > 0 && isThreadAlive){
                int sec = tempTime/1000,
                        min = sec/60;
                int sec1 = sec%60;
                String s = min + " : " + sec1;
                txtRemainingTime.setText(s);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                tempTime -= 1000;
            }
        }
        isThreadAlive = false;
    });

}
```

I said mysterious because of following:

1. I used `View.setText();` both inside and the outside of  `runOnUiThread();`.
2. But `tv.setText();` and `txtRemainingTime.setText(s);` working fine though it's outside of `runOnUiThread();`.
3. At the same time it gives error `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` when I don't use `runOnUiThread();` for that portion of code. It gives error here `txtOp.setText(typeOfOperation);` and `txtQueryCount.setText(count);`.
4. Finally, If I put the following piece of code inside the while loop that was working fine ( even with `txtRemainingTime.setText(s);` gives error for the views inside the following codes.

   `if(i == NUMBER_OF_QUERY - 1){ isThreadAlive = false; btnStart.setEnabled(true); btnSubmit.setEnabled(false); btnCancel.setEnabled(false); setButtonsDisabled(); }`

I want to know, why is like that and how to solve it?

Comment: GUI programming is essentially single-threaded across languages and environments. The thread running the GUI event-handling is the thread that must do all work manipulating the UI.

Comment: That's why we need to use runOnUiThread(), right?
Okay, still I didn't get the solution.
Why is this problem happening to me?
same thing but different result? 
@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @Fahad Not all your calls to change GUI elements are in the runOnUiThread.  Look at the while loop.  It has setText calls.

Comment: But it doesn't give the error in while loop.
Can you please read my whole post?
I really need the solution! :( 
@GabeSechan

Comment: @Fahad you also have one before the runOnUiThread.  EVERY call to setText has to happen on the UI thread.